# How can I speed up this SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, clustered-index

I'm fairly new to SQL, and I'm trying to work out how to speed up a complex SQL query in postgres, perhaps by improving my use of indexes. This is the query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT ev.code FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
        WHERE ev.key_id = :ak_0
        AND ci.entry_id = t.id AND ci.value_id = ev.id) AS axis_0,
    (SELECT ev.code FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
        WHERE ev.key_id = :ak_1
        AND ci.entry_id = t.id AND ci.value_id = ev.id) AS axis_1,
    SUM(t.amount) as amount,
    (SELECT ev.code FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
        WHERE ev.key_id = :key_time_id
        AND ci.entry_id = t.id AND ci.value_id = ev.id) AS time
FROM "entry" t
WHERE t.dataset_id = :dataset_id
AND t.id IN (SELECT ci.entry_id FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
    WHERE ev.key_id = :k_0
    AND ev.code = :v_0 AND ci.value_id = ev.id)
GROUP BY time, axis_0, axis_1
```

This is basically the database schema (as defined in Pylons):

```
table_dataset = Table('dataset', meta.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    )
table_entry = Table('entry', meta.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('dataset_id', Integer, ForeignKey('dataset.id')),
    Column('amount', Float()),
    )
table_classification_item = Table('classification_item', meta.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('entry_id', Integer, ForeignKey('entry.id'), index=True),
    Column('value_id', Integer, ForeignKey('enumeration_value.id'), index=True)
)
table_enumeration_value = Table('enumeration_value', meta.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('key_id', Integer, ForeignKey('key.id'), index=True),
    Column('code', UnicodeText(), index=True),
    )
```

And it has indexes as follows:

```
"dataset_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"entry_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"classification_item_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"ix_classification_item_entry_id" btree (entry_id)
"ix_classification_item_value_id" btree (value_id)
"enumeration_value_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"ix_enumeration_value_code" btree (code)
"ix_enumeration_value_key_id" btree (key_id)
```

Am I missing any obvious index that would speed up the query? In particular:

- should I be using 'clustered' indexes?
- should I also be indexing `amount` on `entry`, or would that make no difference to `SUM(t.amount) as amount`?

Thanks for your help. I know this is a pretty complex question, so please tell me if I can do anything to improve it.

------ UPDATE --------------

[The output from EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/285548/) on the above query.

Comment: would be helpful if you post the explain plan

Comment: As a rule you should always have clustered indexes.  There are some rare exceptions but they are **really** rare.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm a bit confused about what a 'clustered' index actually is. Are the indexes I have above actually clustered? I was wondering if I could create a 'joint' index on two keys at once...

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-cluster.html

Comment: @AP257 - A clustered index organizes the pages physically on the key  that you specify.  Think of it like a table of contents for the "book" of your table.  Non-clustered indexes are like the index in the back of  the book - they tell you what page the data is on.  For your query, covering (or joint) indexes won't matter much because it looks like almost all of your selects are on single fields.  Unless you routinely query two or more fields together in the same query, they aren't much use.

Comment: @JNK: `PostgreSQL` does not support clustered indexes.

Comment: @Quassnoi - well then nevermind :)

Comment: Ah OK thank you. Hm. My other question is, should I be indexing 'amount'?

Comment: @Quassnoi - the docs (link posted by @Andy) seem to suggest that postgresql does support some clustered indexes?

Comment: @AP257: did you read the link? *Clustering is a one-time operation: when the table is subsequently updated, the changes are not clustered. That is, no attempt is made to store new or updated rows according to their index order*. `CLUSTER` reorders a heap-based table according to an index, but does not maintain the order, and the table remains heap-based.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. My data is static - I won't be updating it - so that's not necessarily a problem for me, just as long as I can query it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `enumeration_value` table is small, I guess you can get some improvment by making `axis_1` and `axis_0` as join and add an extra index.

something like this (not tested)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ci_vi_ei ON classification_item(value_id, entry_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_id_ki ON enumeration_value(id, key_id);

SELECT
    ci_0.code AS axis_0,
    ci_1.code AS axis_1,
    SUM(t.amount) as amount,
    ci_t.code AS time
FROM 
   "entry" t,
   (SELECT ev.code FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
        WHERE ev.key_id = :ak_0 AND ci.value_id = ev.id) ci_0,
   (SELECT ev.code FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
        WHERE ev.key_id = :ak_1 AND ci.value_id = ev.id) ci_1,
   (SELECT ev.code FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
        WHERE ev.key_id = :key_time_id AND ci.value_id = ev.id) ci_t
WHERE t.dataset_id = :dataset_id 
AND t.id IN (SELECT ci.entry_id FROM classification_item ci, enumeration_value ev
    WHERE ev.key_id = :k_0
    AND ev.code = :v_0 AND ci.value_id = ev.id)
AND t.id = ci_0.entry_id AND t.id = ci_1.entry_id AND t.id = ci_t.entry_id
GROUP BY time, axis_0, axis_1
```

Comment: enumeration_value is large, alas... so are entry and classification_item. only dataset and key are small.

Answer (score 0):

What has [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to say about the queryplan?